# Giving Error while uploading video to Firebase->FireStorage. [error] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-storage, flutter-getx

I'm trying to upload video from gallery and it's giving me error but it's working fine for upload video from camera in my android 13 physical device. when i tried to upload video from my android 8 emulator it's working fine for both Camera and gallery.

Error :-

[image]

I'm getting this error when i try to upload video from gallery.

below is code of method for picking video.

```
  videoPicker(ImageSource src) async {
    final video = await ImagePicker().pickVideo(source: src);
    if (video != null) {
      Get.to(
          AddCaptionScreen(videoFile: File(video.path), videoPath: video.path));
    } else {
      Get.snackbar("Error Occurred",
          "Error Occurred while Selecting video. Please try again");
    }
  }
```

below is code of GetxController for uploading videl =>

```
 uploadVideo(String songName, String caption, String videoPath) async {

    try{
      String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

      DocumentSnapshot userDoc =
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(uid).get();

      String videoID = uuid.v1();

      String videoUrl = await _uploadVideoToStorage(videoID, videoPath);  // THIRD LINE ERROR HERE

      String thumbnail = await _uploadVideoThumbtoStorage(videoID, videoPath);

      VideoModel videoModel =  VideoModel(username:  (userDoc.data()! as Map<String , dynamic>)['name'], uid: uid, thumbnail: thumbnail, caption: caption, commentsCount: 0, videoID: videoID, likes: [], profilePic: (userDoc.data()! as Map<String , dynamic>)['profilePic'], shareCount: 0, songName: songName, videoUrl: videoUrl);

      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("videos").doc(videoID).set(videoModel.toJson());
      Get.snackbar("Video Uploaded Successfully", "Thank You Sharing Your Content");
      Get.back();
    }catch (e){
      print(e);
      rethrow;
    }

  }

  // below function used to Compress and upload video to firestorage
  Future<String> _uploadVideoToStorage(String videoId, String videoPath) async {
    print("VideoID  ------->   $videoId ,,   VideoPath -------> $videoPath");
    Reference reference =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("videos").child(videoId);     // SECOND LINE ERROR HERE





    UploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile( await _compressVideo(videoPath));
    TaskSnapshot snapshot = await uploadTask;
    String downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadUrl;
  }

  _compressVideo(String videoPath) async {
    final compressedVideo = await VideoCompress.compressVideo(videoPath,
        quality: VideoQuality.MediumQuality);
    return compressedVideo!.file;                                          // FIRST LINE ERROR HERE
  }

  //below functions used for Generate Thumbnail and upload on firestorage
  Future<File> _generateThumbnail(String videoPath) async {
    final thumbnail = await VideoCompress.getFileThumbnail(videoPath);
    return thumbnail;
  }

  Future<String> _uploadVideoThumbtoStorage(String id, String videoPath) async {
    Reference reference =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("thumbnail").child(id);
    UploadTask uploadTask =
        reference.putFile(await _generateThumbnail(videoPath));
    TaskSnapshot snapshot = await uploadTask;
    String downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadUrl;
  }
}
```

I tried to upload video with good internet speed. but giving me same error. I'm also playing video after picking and it's playing normally in both android 8 emulator and android 13 physical device. Also tried to add permission in AndroidManifest.xml but nothing changed i coz it's picking video and playing too but just not getting uploaded.